# Question regarding fuses

Tags: components, fuses, polyfuse

What is the difference between thermal fuse and MOV and polyfuse.Which is faster and also which companies produce polyfuse, especially in Asia.

I have to search for a component that can save my circuit which is connected via  a TRIAC to a submersible motor. In it may happen that the live and gnd wires may touch due to rupturing of the overhead seal. This would send a surge that cant be handled by TRIAC. A fast fuse is a temporary solution which has to be changed everytime, so i wanted to ask if Polyfuse was viable in its place.

Comment: Tell us a bit more about background and application. What is 'fast' or 'fast enough'? What sort of circuit are you using/designing, ... The more you tell us, the better answer we can give you.

Answer (score 6):

- [Thermal fuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_fuse):
  Goes open circuit when the temperature reaches a certain value. Comes in non-resettable and resettable varieties.
- [MOV (Metal-Oxide Varistor)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor):
  This is not a fuse at all. It is a device that begins to conduct when the voltage across it exceeds a certain value. MOVs are used to absorb high-voltage pulses, hopefully for long enough to blow a upstream fuse or circuit breaker.

  If you don't have a fuse or circuit breaker upstream from the MOV, you usually get a fire.
- [Polyfuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfuse):
  A Polyfuse is a self-resetting fuse. Basically, the way they work, when you have a certain amount of current flowing though a polyfuse, it goes open circuit for a period of time.

  Generally, they're thermal in mechanism. Once they heat up to a certain point, their resistance increases dramatically. Then, they stay high-impedance until their temperature decays back again.

---

Anything else, and we'll need more information about your application. It sounds like you're in a bit over your head.